# Calling Fortran from C++; String on return corrupted

Tags: c++, string, fortran

I am calling a Fortran 77 Function from C++ that passes a file handle, a string, and the length. The files opens successfully and the Fortran subroutine exits. However, back in the C++ Code the string, which was passed to fortran, is corrupted. When the bottom of the function openFile is reached the program crashes.

The crash only appears in release but not in debug. Plotting the strings, I see that in release the variable fileNameToFortran is full of trash.

Thanks for your help

I use ifort with following compiler flags in release (windows 7 machine (32 bit)):
/names:lowercase /f77rtl /traceback /iface:cref /threads /recursive /LD

and in debug:
/names:lowercase /f77rtl /traceback /iface:cref /threads /recursive /LDd /Zi /debug:full /check:all /traceback

---

Here is the C-Code:

```
typedef void  (FORTCALL *sn_openfile_func) (int *,
                                            char[],
                                            int *,
                                            int);
void openFile(const int fileHandle, const std::string fileName)
{
  int fileHandleToFortran = fileHandle; 
  char fileNameToFortran[20]; 
  assert(fileName.size() < 20);

  strcpy(fileNameToFortran, fileName.c_str()); 
  int lstr = strlen(fileNameToFortran);
  openfile_func_handle(&fileHandleToFortran, fileNameToFortran, &lstr, lstr);
}
```

Here is the Fortran Code:

```
      SUBROUTINE SN_OPENFILE(FILENR,FILENAME,FSIZE)
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: SN_OPENFILE
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER FILENR, FSIZE
      CHARACTER FILENAME*FSIZE
      OPEN (FILENR,FILE = FILENAME, 
     &       ACCESS = 'SEQUENTIAL' , STATUS = 'REPLACE', ERR=222)
      GOTO 333
222   WRITE(*,*) 'Error opening file'
333   END
```

Comment: Where is the Fortran routine invoked? Is it `openfile_func_handle`? In that case, why do yo pass 4 arguments, while `ṠN_OPENFILE`˙only expects 3?

Comment: In this era I would use the Fortran ISO C Binding to mix C/C++ and Fortran. This provides a standard way of interfacing the language instead of having to figure out the calling conventions of particular compilers, such as adding string lengths to the end of the argument list.  Such conventions are non-portable and subject to change. Most Fortran 95 compilers have this feature, which is part of Fortran 2003.  (Even besides wanting to use the ISO C Binding, I'd use Fortran 95/2003 instead of FORTRAN 77.)  The ifort and gfortran manuals have examples; also questions here.

Comment: See the answer below. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer myself.

The macro FORTCALL was defined as __STDCALL
Now, when using iface:cref it only crashes in release. That is strange, but after I have removed it, it works for release and debug.

Comment: One more reason to use the ISO C binding features of Fortran as suggested by M.S.B. That should hopefully work without any big surprises.